# How to make LINQ to EF and LINQ to ordinary collection return the same values?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I use LINQ to EF.

I have an Item entity which has a collection of Purchases.

Not all Items have Purchases. I want to make a Select query which when the item has no purchases - it returns null for LastPurchaseQuantity(int?) and LastPurchaseDate(DateTime?).

I made following LINQ SELECT query.

When I run it in the application to EF - it returns exactly what I want. But when I try to Unit test it - it returns the default values for LastPurchaseQuantity and LastPurchaseDate - Min Date and 0.

How should I optimize my query so it works the same way against EF and in the Unit tests? It should return the value or null.

I imagine I need not a FirstOrDefault, but FirstOrNull() method.

```
        var query = _itemsRepository.All()
            .Where(x => x.UserId == userId)
            .Select(x => new ItemOverviewDto()
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                Name = x.Name,
                ReplenishmentPeriod = x.ReplenishmentPeriod,
                NextReplenishmentDate = x.NextReplenishmentDate,

                LastReplenishmentDate = x.Purchases
                                 .OrderByDescending(y => y.ReplenishmentDate)
                                 .Select(m => m.ReplenishmentDate)
                                 .FirstOrDefault(),

                LastReplenishmentQuantity = x.Purchases
                                 .OrderByDescending(y => y.ReplenishmentDate)
                                 .Select(m => m.Quantity)
                                 .FirstOrDefault(),
            });

        return query.ToList();
```

Edit: For my Unit test I pass a fake IQueryable collection.

```
var allItems = BuildItemsCollection();
ItemsRepositoryMock.Setup(x => x.All()).Returns(allItems);
```

Comment: Don't do that, unittest is not for querying DB. Why do you want to get values from database in unit test?

Comment: I don't use the DB in my Unit test. I use Moq to pass a fake IQueryable<Item> collection to the test.

Comment: Okay then add your unit-test code as well and explain how you mocked repository.

Comment: I added the code of the Unit test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only option I see is to add type conversion to nullable types:

```
        LastReplenishmentDate = x.Purchases
                         .OrderByDescending(y => y.ReplenishmentDate)
                         .Select(m => (DateTime?) m.ReplenishmentDate)
                         .FirstOrDefault(),

        LastReplenishmentQuantity = x.Purchases
                         .OrderByDescending(y => y.ReplenishmentDate)
                         .Select(m => (int?) m.Quantity)
                         .FirstOrDefault(),
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your BuildItemsCollection method set up the returned Items include a populated Purchases collection? EF will translate Linq expressions into SQL so the behaviour can be a bit different than when you are querying against objects.

One recommendation when defining entities with collection navigation properties is to always initialize those navigation properties:

I.e.

```
public class Item
{
     // Item fields...

     public virtual ICollection<Purchase> Purchases { get; set; } = new List<Purchase>();
}
```

This just helps avoid null reference exceptions when accessing Purchases on a new item. However in your case check that BuildItemsCollection is populating Purchases:

```
private IQueryable<Item> BuildItemsCollection()
{
    var items = new List<Item> ( new [] 
    {
         new Item 
         {
             // ....
             Purchases = new List<Purchase> ( new []   
             { 
                 new Purchase // Expected purchase..
                 {
                     // ..
                 },
                 new Purchase 
                 {
                     // ..
                 }
             }
        },
        new Item 
        {
             // ...
             Purchases = new List<Purchase> ( new []   
             { 
                 new Purchase // Expected purchase..
                 {
                     // ..
                 },
             }
        }
    }
    return items.AsQueryable();
}
```

Update:

An additional consideration when working with in-memory sets vs. database in the way of database collation and any filtering you do by string. Depending on your database collation settings, the DB may be operating in case-insensitive mode (default for SQL Server) so queries like:

```
.Where(x => x.Name = "george")
```

when run against a table with "George" as a name with a CI collation, this will return a record. When run against an in-memory `IQueryable` of populated objects, it won't. (Worth considering if/when testing filters on data)

Comment: Yes, I have initialized the Purchases collection in the Item entity exactly as you have described. In the BuildItemsCollection() method I assign Purchases only to some items - and this is intentionally since it is normal for some items not to have purchases. With the initialized items - there is no problem - they return the last purchase date to the Dto as expected. The problem I have described arrises only with the Items where the Purchases collection is empty.